# Заполнение данных в html из php по id

Tags: javascript, php, phpexcel

Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста.
Есть html с таблицей

```
<table class="secondtable">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>input</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="secondtabletd">Number of FCB request in last 30 
days</td>
        <td class="secondtabletd"></td>
        <td class="secondtabletd"><input></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

По нажатию на кнопку сохраняются данные из input в php, который обрабатывает их через Excel.
Получаю данные из Excel (PHPExcel) Как мне теперь добавить эти данные из php в

```
  <td class="secondtabletd"></td>
```

Если подключаю через required_once, то выводится ошибка не заполненных данных в input. Да и файл excel не успевает обрабатываться - соответственно не те данные выводит.

Comment: Что за данные берутся из input'a? Как они обрабатываются на сервере? Что подключаете через required_once? Почему phpexcel, а не phpspreadsheet, когда первый deprecated? Где вы выводите циклом данные из таблицы?

Comment: Вы в вопросе показали только какую-то абстрактную таблицу. Откуда мы должны знать, что у вас происходит в php скрипте?

Comment: К чему вообще остальные скрипты? Да так, ни к чему, мы же сами должны разобраться, где у вас что находится, откуда нужно что выводить и т.д.. Вы сами делаете все, чтобы на ваш вопрос никто не ответил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный вариант, который нашёл - создал новый файл php. 
В нём привязал через require_once файла php с обработчиком. 
В конце добавил include файла html, и уже в него хорошо все данные вставились. 
Соответственно для запуска формы html использую новый созданный файл php - он выводит и форму html и добавляет данные  из обработчика.